# How to load the different format of json to Highchart

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, highcharts

here is my json data can anyone guide me how to load this data to HighCharts. this is sample data.

```
{
"Type": [
    "Tower",
    "Apartment",
    "Atrium",
    "Terrace"
       ],
"Freq": [
    21,
    21,
    28,
    34,
    22,
    36,
    10,
    11,
    36,
    61,
    23,
    17,
    43,
    35,
    40,
    26,
    18,
    54,
    13,
    9,
    10,
    8,
    8,
    12,
    6,
    7,
    9,
    18,
    6,
    7,
    15,
    13,
    13,
    7,
    5,
    11,
    14,
    19,
    37,
    17,
    23,
    40,
    3,
    5,
    23,
    78,
    46,
    43,
    48,
    45,
    86,
    15,
    25,
    62,
    20,
    23,
    20,
    10,
    22,
    24,
    7,
    10,
    21,
    57,
    23,
    13,
    31,
    21,
    13,
    5,
    6,
    13
]
```

}

Actual the json format is this only i am getting. so please anyone guide me. This is the data which is passing to Highcharts to draw chart. when i pass this data it not at all showing the chart.

Comment: Which graph you are using in highchart ?

Comment: Where do you want to place those 4 types?? this data doesn't make sense, it either should be separate data for each type or type dont need to be mentioned in chart?

Comment: @NitinKaushal any type of chart like bar,column,line like this

Comment: @AbdulJabbar oh then ok we will leave the types but tell me how to hot to load the Freq to the Y-axis.

Comment: check my answer for loading values on Y-Axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to simply display that data on Y-Axis, use the below code (considering your object is named "data":

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: "Showing Frequencies",
    },
    series: [{
        name: "Frequencies",
        data: data.Freq
    }]

});
```

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/3428/)**

Comment: Yes it working thank you. can u tell me how to get the name of the data fiels like (Type,Freq) i need these names. not getting how to get them. i tried data.name but it now working.

Comment: data.Type[0] will give you "Tower"... data.Type[1] wil give you "Apartment" and so on...

Comment: no i need the names of column. like Type,Freq these values. not the data within them.

Comment: Just use "Type" "Freq" you'll have to hardcode them.. Cant get those names programtically

Comment: sorry about earlier reply.. you can get them programatically through: var names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data);  this will return the array of all the properties of your object.. http://jsfiddle.net/473euz0n/

Comment: here i am writing the code for x-axis update. but it not showing data.

options.categories=[{
     data: json.City
    }]
     options.series= [{
          data: json.Order_Quantity
      }]
     chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

Comment: For everything same i need to add x-axis data too please anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Make the proper series like this

```
 series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
```